# Adding a logo while keeping the design and responsiveness same

Tags: html, css

I want to add a logo from font-awesome on the left of the home link in the nav bar. But when I added it the design of the entire page is ruined. I wanted all the links in the navbar in a single line but as soon as added that icon position of all the elements in ruined. Please someone suggest an edit such that the icon remains there as well as the design and responsiveness changes.

```css
body{
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    background-color: #091118;
}
nav{
    position: relative;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-size: 0;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 3px 0;       
    width: 100%; 
    height: 50px; 
    border-radius: 15px;
    background-color: #04111ffa;
}
nav a{
    width: 100%;
    font-size: 15px;
    color: seashell;
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    display: inline-block;
    line-height: 50px;
    z-index: 5;
    text-align: center;
}
.search-container{
    float: right;
}
input[type=text]{
    padding: 6px;
    margin-top: 13px;
    font-size: 17px;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 15px;
}
.search-container button{
    float: right;
    padding: 6px 10px;
    margin-top: 13px;
    margin-right: 30px;
    font-size: 17px;
    border-radius: 15px;
    background-color: rgb(58, 233, 218);
}
span.fas {
    max-width: 50px;
}
```

```html
    <nav>
        <span class="fas fa-bars"></span>
        <a href="#">Home</a>
        <a href="#">About</a>
        <a href="#">Contact</a>
        <a href="#">Privacy Policy</a>
        <a href="#">Docs</a>
        <div class="animation start-home"></div>
        <div class="search-container">
            <form>
                <input type="text" placeholder="Search..." name="search" class="searchbar">
                <button type="submit"><i class="fas fa-search"></i><span class="text">Search</span></button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </nav>
```

Comment: I’m a bit lost as to why you have given the anchor elements a width of 100% if you want them in one line ( I realise this is not related to adding an icon). Please could you check your snippet so it shows us your stated problem. This will include adding the fontawesome code.

Answer (score 0):

```css
body{
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    background-color: #091118;
}
nav{
    position: relative;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-size: 0;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 3px 0;       
    width: 100%; 
    height: 50px; 
    border-radius: 15px;
    background-color: #04111ffa;
}
nav a{
    width: 100%;
    font-size: 15px;
    color: seashell;
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    display: inline-block;
    line-height: 50px;
    z-index: 5;
    text-align: center;
}
.search-container{
    float: right;
}
input[type=text]{
    padding: 6px;
    margin-top: 13px;
    font-size: 17px;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 15px;
}
.search-container button{
    float: right;
    padding: 6px 10px;
    margin-top: 13px;
    margin-right: 30px;
    font-size: 17px;
    border-radius: 15px;
    background-color: rgb(58, 233, 218);
}
span.fas {
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 20px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
   
    <nav>
        <span class="fas fa-bars">bars</span>
        <a href="#">Home</a>
        <a href="#">About</a>
        <a href="#">Contact</a>
        <a href="#">Privacy Policy</a>
        <a href="#">Docs</a>
        <div class="animation start-home"></div>
        <div class="search-container">
            <form>
                <input type="text" placeholder="Search..." name="search" class="searchbar">
                <button type="submit"><i class="fas fa-search"></i><span class="text">Search</span></button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </nav>
```

Comment: It's not working the icon is appearing but I want it on left of the navbar such that all the other elements in nav bar are in a single horizontal line

Comment: you need to paste your whole header code this is just a navbar

Comment: I don't have any header code. I made only this